# AccessDecisionVoter Deprecated with Spring Security 6.x

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

In Spring Boot 2.7.x , I used the [`RoleHierarchyVoter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/vote/RoleHierarchyVoter.html)

```java
public RoleHierarchy roleHierarchy() {
    RoleHierarchyImpl roleHierarchy = new RoleHierarchyImpl();
    roleHierarchy.setHierarchy("ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR > ROLE_USER > ROLE_GUEST");
    return roleHierarchy;
}

@Bean
public RoleHierarchyVoter roleVoter() {
    return new RoleHierarchyVoter(roleHierarchy());
}
```

In Spring Boot 3.x [`AccessDecisionVoter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/6.0.x/api/org/springframework/security/access/vote/RoleVoter.html) are deprecated - the use of [`AuthorizationManager`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/6.0.x/api/org/springframework/security/authorization/AuthorityAuthorizationManager.html) is recommended. Is there any posibility to use an AuthorizationManager-Implementation to set a role hierarchy? The usage of

```java
@Bean
AccessDecisionVoter hierarchyVoter() {
    RoleHierarchy hierarchy = new RoleHierarchyImpl();
    hierarchy.setHierarchy("ROLE_ADMIN > ROLE_STAFF > ROLE_USER" +
            "ROLE_USER > ROLE_GUEST");
    return new RoleHierarchyVoter(hierarchy);
}
```

did not work since I use the `AuthorizationFilter`.

Comment: This might help you https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/authorization.html#_replace_any_custom_method_security_accessdecisionmanagers

Answer (score 2):

Simply exposing a `expressionHandler` bean should do the job.

If you use method security (`@EnableMethodSecurity`) :

```java
@Bean
public RoleHierarchyImpl roleHierarchy() {
    final RoleHierarchyImpl roleHierarchy = new RoleHierarchyImpl();
    roleHierarchy.setHierarchy("ROLE_ADMIN > ROLE_STAFF > ROLE_USER > ROLE_GUEST");
    return roleHierarchy;
}

@Bean
public DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler() {
    DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler = new DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
    expressionHandler.setRoleHierarchy(roleHierarchy());
    return expressionHandler;
}
```

If you use web security (`@EnableWebSecurity`) :

```java
@Bean
public RoleHierarchyImpl roleHierarchy() {
    final RoleHierarchyImpl roleHierarchy = new RoleHierarchyImpl();
    roleHierarchy.setHierarchy("ROLE_ADMIN > ROLE_STAFF > ROLE_USER > ROLE_GUEST");
    return roleHierarchy;
}

@Bean
public DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler() {
    DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler = new DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler();
    expressionHandler.setRoleHierarchy(roleHierarchy());
    return expressionHandler;
}
```

Comment: This does not work. I filed an issue in spring security team https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/12473

Comment: I implemented this solution which is working in spring security 6.0.0 and spring boot 3.0.0 https://stackoverflow.com/a/74942274/910598

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Actually this is what I use with Spring Boot 3 and Spring Security 6 and it works totally fine, at least for method security (`@PreAuthorize`).

Comment: It works fine (Spring Boot 3.0.2) but I had to annotate the class also with @Configuration; which it was not necessary in Spring Boot 2.7.x

Answer (score 0):

First, you create and instance of `AuthorizationManager`:

```java
var access = AuthorityAuthorizationManager.<RequestAuthorizationContext>hasRole("USER");
```

This instance will be used to authorize our endpoints. So in the `hasRole` method, provide the name of your role or roles you want to use to protect a specific endpoint.

Second, you define your role hierarchy:

```java
var hierarchy = new RoleHierarchyImpl();
hierarchy.setHierarchy("ROLE_ADMIN > ROLE_USER");
```

In this case we are defining that `ROLE_ADMIN` is above `ROLE_USER`, so `ROLE_ADMIN` has the same role as an `ROLE_USER`.

Third, we set the `RoleHierarcy` instance in the `AuthorizationManager` instance:

```java
access.setRoleHierarchy(hierarchy);
```

Finally, we set the `AuthorizationManager` instance in our route protection configuration. So all the code togheter would look like this:

```
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        var access = AuthorityAuthorizationManager.<RequestAuthorizationContext>hasRole("USER");
        var hierarchy = new RoleHierarchyImpl();
        hierarchy.setHierarchy("ROLE_ADMIN > ROLE_USER");
        access.setRoleHierarchy(hierarchy);

        http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize.anyRequest().access(access));

        return http.build();

    }
```