# Roles hierarchy not working after upgrading to spring security 6

Tags: spring, security, configuration, upgrade

I am upgrading from spring boot 2.7.x to 3.0.0. After doing changes as recommended in  the official docs I found that my role hierarchies are not being honored.

I added `expressionHandler()` to my code as suggested in  [AccessDecisionVoter Deprecated with Spring Security 6.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74763256/accessdecisionvoter-deprecated-with-spring-security-6-x) but it doesn't work.

Any ideas what am I missing?

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain configure(
      HttpSecurity http,
      RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter headerAuthenticationFilter) throws Exception {
    
    HttpStatusEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint = 
        new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
    
    http
        .addFilterAfter(headerAuthenticationFilter, RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
          .requestMatchers("/actuator/**", "/", "/webjars/**").permitAll()
          .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST).hasRole("SUPERUSER")
          .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET).hasRole("USER"))
        .sessionManagement(session -> session
          .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
        .exceptionHandling(ex -> ex
          .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
          .accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler()))
        .csrf(customizer -> customizer.disable());

    return http.build();
  }

  @Bean
  public RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter headerAuthenticationFilter(
      ...
  }

  @Bean
  public RoleHierarchy roleHierarchy() {
    RoleHierarchyImpl r = new RoleHierarchyImpl();
    r.setHierarchy("ROLE_SUPERUSER > ROLE_USER");
    return r;
  }

  @Bean
  public DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler() {
    DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler = new DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler();
    expressionHandler.setRoleHierarchy(roleHierarchy());
    return expressionHandler;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

AuthorityAuthorizationManager is not exposed as a bean. Indeed it is a final class with private constructor. So in order to use my role hierarchy I need to create manually the AuthorityAuthorizationManager.

This worked using spring boot 3.0.0 and spring security 6.0.0

```
  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain configure(
      HttpSecurity http,
      RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter headerAuthenticationFilter) throws Exception {

    var auth1 = AuthorityAuthorizationManager.<RequestAuthorizationContext>hasRole("USER");
    auth1.setRoleHierarchy(roleHierarchy());
    
    http
        .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
          .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET).access(auth1)
        );
    return http.build();
  }

 @Bean
  public RoleHierarchy roleHierarchy() {
    RoleHierarchyImpl r = new RoleHierarchyImpl();
    r.setHierarchy("ROLE_SUPERUSER > ROLE_USER");
    return r;
  }
```

Comment: Did you come across any better alternative?

Comment: @securecurve Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/75727359/6667813

Answer (score 0):

The best way I found was to call into `GrantedAuthoritiesMapper#mapAuthorities` the same way [AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/main/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/authentication/dao/AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java#L197) does it.
Unfortunately [PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/main/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/preauth/PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider.java#L99) does not call into it the same way so you will have to do it yourself.

This will make it work everywhere including method security and other places than HttpSecurity. It's probably the right way given most auth providers are doing it. Also it will avoid expanding hierarchy per every check.

```java
  @Bean
  public GrantedAuthoritiesMapper grantedAuthoritiesMapper(RoleHierarchy roleHierarchy) {
      return new RoleHierarchyAuthoritiesMapper(roleHierarchy);
  }

  @Bean
  public RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter headerAuthenticationFilter(GrantedAuthoritiesMapper mapper) {
      var filter = new RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter();
      //...
      filter.setAuthenticationDetailsSource(context -> {
          //...
          return new PreAuthenticatedGranteduthoritiesWebAuthenticationDetails(context, mapper.mapAuthorities(authorities));
      });
      return filter;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

A also have a hierarchy - ROLE_EDIT > ROLE_READ. A solution from my small project after migration from Spring Boot 2 to Spring Boot 3 is:

```
@Bean
public AuthorizationManager<RequestAuthorizationContext> authorizationManager_READ(RoleHierarchy roleHierarchy) {
    return (authentication, object) -> {
        AuthorityAuthorizationManager<RequestAuthorizationContext> authorityAuthorizationManager = AuthorityAuthorizationManager.hasAnyAuthority("ROLE_READ");
        authorityAuthorizationManager.setRoleHierarchy(roleHierarchy);

        return authorityAuthorizationManager.check(authentication, object);
    };
}
```

in filterChain

```
.requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/internal-order/**").access(authorizationManager_READ)
```

Maybe not the best solution, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

From [Spring Boot 3.0.3](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/releases/tag/v3.0.3) onward, you can define `RoleHierarchy` as a `@Bean` and it will be determined by the `AuthorizeHttpRequestsConfigurer` and set to the `AuthorityAuthorizationManager` using its setter.

```java
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.access.hierarchicalroles.RoleHierarchy;
import org.springframework.security.access.hierarchicalroles.RoleHierarchyImpl;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public RoleHierarchy roleHierarchy() {
        RoleHierarchyImpl roleHierarchy = new RoleHierarchyImpl();
        String hierarchy = "ROLE_ADMIN > ROLE_MODERATOR \n ROLE_MODERATOR > ROLE_USER";
        roleHierarchy.setHierarchy(hierarchy);
        return roleHierarchy;
    }

    // ...
}
```

The actual issue was fixed in [Spring Security 6.1.0-M1](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/releases/tag/6.1.0-M1).

Comment: Thanks! But how is that answer different from the one given by David below?

Comment: In David's approach, the `AuthorityAuthorizationManager` is explicitly set for one specific `RequestMatcher`. However, here the `RoleHierarchy` is exposed globally and you can use this in any route without needing to set the `access()`.

Answer (score 0):

Since the current release of Spring Boot I am using is 3.0.5, the fix mentioned by bytesandcaffeine here https://stackoverflow.com/a/75727359/2236002 does not exist yet. So the simple solution I found is to create a DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler bean and set my role hierarchy to it.